# Update last element in .SD group based on other elements

Tags: r, data.table, data-cleaning

I have a dataset `dt` in data.table format that looks like

```
  type id val

1 m     1   5
2 m     1   3
3 m     1  NA
3 e     2   7
4 e     3   7
5 m     4   4
6 m     4   2
7 m     4  NA
```

I want to replace `val` of the last entry (in my example `NA`) of each group by `id` of type `m` with the sum of `val` of the other entries of the group. I.e., I want to end up with a dataset like this:

```
  type id val

1 m     1   5
2 m     1   3
3 m     1   8
3 e     2   7
4 e     3   7
5 m     4   4
6 m     4   2
7 m     4   6
```

Currently, I am trying to wrap my head around data.table functions, particularly .SD and want to solve the issue with these tools.

So far, I have figured out that `dt[type=="m",.SD[.N],.SDcols="val",by=id]` gives me access to the relevant elements and `dt[type=="m", lapply(.SD[1:.N-1]),.SDcols="val",by=id]` provides me with the correct sum. However, I can't bring the two together.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `replace` :

```
library(data.table)

dt[type == "m", val := replace(val, .N, sum(val, na.rm = TRUE)), id]
dt

#   type id val
#1:    m  1   5
#2:    m  1   3
#3:    m  1   8
#4:    e  2   7
#5:    e  3   7
#6:    m  4   4
#7:    m  4   2
#8:    m  4   6
```

Comment: Thanks. I used `dt[type == "m", val := replace(val, .N, sum(val[-.N], na.rm = TRUE)), id]` as I can't rely on `NA`s for sure. But I got the idea.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `na.aggregate`

```
library(zoo)
library(data.table)
setDT(dt)[type == 'm', val := na.aggregate(val,  FUN = sum), id]
dt
#   type id val
#1:    m  1   5
#2:    m  1   3
#3:    m  1   8
#4:    e  2   7
#5:    e  3   7
#6:    m  4   4
#7:    m  4   2
#8:    m  4   6
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(dt)[type == 'm', val := c(val[-.N], sum(val, na.rm = TRUE)), by = id]
```

Output:

```
   type id val
1:    m  1   5
2:    m  1   3
3:    m  1   8
4:    e  2   7
5:    e  3   7
6:    m  4   4
7:    m  4   2
8:    m  4   6
```